# Add panel under screenshot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with adding description to screenshot. I capture camera screen like this:

```
    RenderTexture texture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 32);
    Camera.main.targetTexture = texture;
    RenderTexture.active = texture;
    Camera.main.Render();
    Texture2D texture2D = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    texture2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    texture2D.Apply();
```

Now I'm trying to add white panel with labels under captured screen and then save it to file. And now I have a problem. I don't know how to merge panel with image. I tried to add panel on canvas and then use **Application.CaptureScreenshot();** but it doesn't work as I want. The panel appears on the screenshot but cover some elements. How can I put panel under the screenshot?

Thank you for your help!

[image: What I have now. Panel is on the screenshot range]
What I have now. Panel is on the screenshot range

[image: What I'm trying to do. Panel is added under screenshot range and doesn't cover anything]
What I'm trying to do. Panel is added under screenshot range and doesn't cover anything

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you **want** and what you currently have?

Comment: I'd just work with .NET drawing namespace here, after the texture has been made available as a flat bitmap, extending the captured image vertically and `DrawString`-ing the label.

Comment: @mjwills :
I'm sorry. Sure I can